# Way to resend activation link and send change password link in flow (SOLVED)

Tags: community, user-management, reset-password, change-password

I thought i would share a solution to a couple of issues I've been having and have noticed loads of other people asking similar questions, without many viable solutions.

This relates specifically to Experience Cloud community users.

1. Resending an account activation link - POSSIBLE (with limitations)
   This can be achieved by changing the user to a different profile (without community access) and then back into the community profile.
   Doing this will resend the welcome (activation) email.
   **NOTE!!** The link in the welcome email will only be a full activation link if the user account "Email Verification" field is FALSE and the Last Login date is empty.
   As soon as the activation link is clicked (even if no password is set), the email verification field is set to TRUE and the last login date is updated to today.
   **Therefore, this only works once.** But depending on your use case, this may be enough.
2. A better & repeatable solution, which replicates the "generate new password and notify user immediately" action can be achieved using the user management utilities salesforce  labs released last year on app exchange.
   This extension makes an Apex Action available to use in a flow that takes in a userid and triggers CREATE Password.
   The key with this being so much better than "reset password" is that the link can be clicked multiple times (once the password is set, it no longer works), and it should reduce the instances of users being sent is that terrible loop.

It can be used by internal staff to easily change passwords for external users without having to go all the way to the user object.
However, I have actually set this up a flow on my community to enable a better reset password experience.

I hope this is useful information to someone out there. I felt it was worth sharing, as in my own searches I have found countless people posting about similar issues with very few solutions.

LINKS
User Experience Utilites - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3u00000PuquwEAB&tab=r

Extension for Person Accounts - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3u00000QsAPQEA3&tab=e

Video talking about these utilities (password info around a the 7 minute mark)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B2HgHVY5aTM

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. What problem is your first bullet solving? Second problem: Password reset link being clickable once has an out of the box solution: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386502&type=1

Comment: Your question is several questions and answers. This is not a useful format for StackExchange. Why not split everything up into several questions and add your own answers separately to them?! This is okay. Otherwise I suggest to create an article on the given subject somewhere else.

Comment: I guess this is why it's impossible to find this information when searching for answers to these issues. 
Here I was thinking this would be helpful to someone who's searching (there are LOADS of questions asking for this information), never mind. Feel free to delete this if it doesn't conform to the right standards. I was only trying to help other people.